# C++ pthread_create will not print in function

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have this program that will run a thread when the user type "run"

The problem is

```
printf("\n%s", message); //will not be printed out
```

If you uncomment the for loop inside printMsg(), the output is like this

```
Hello World COUNTER: 0
Hello World COUNTER: 1
```

But I'm expecting something like

```
Hello World COUNTER: 0
Hello World COUNTER: 1
Hello World COUNTER: 2
```

**Am I missing something to run pthread correctly?**
The Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

struct ThreadStruct
{
    const char *filename;
    int noOfRepeat;
    int interval;
};

void *printMsg( void *ptr )
{
    struct ThreadStruct *args = (struct ThreadStruct *)ptr;
    const char *message = args->filename;
    int noOfRepeat = args->noOfRepeat;
    int interval = args->interval;

    printf("\n%s", message);

    /*
    for(int i=0; i<noOfRepeat; i++){
         printf("\n%s COUNTER: %d", message, i);
         sleep(interval);
    }
    */
}


int main()
{

    char* input = NULL;

    do {
        //get input from user
        input = readline("Input: ");

        //check if input is run
        if(strcmp(input, "run") == 0){

            //create a thread to run print_message_function
            struct ThreadStruct *myStruct;
            myStruct = (ThreadStruct *) malloc(sizeof(ThreadStruct));
            myStruct->filename = "Hello World";
            myStruct->noOfRepeat = 3;
            myStruct->interval = 3;

            pthread_t thread;
            pthread_create( &thread, NULL, printMsg, (void*) myStruct);
        }
    } while(strcmp(input, "exit") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

FYI, I use this to compile

```
g++ main.cpp -lreadline -lpthread -o main
```

Comment: Your code is doing everything correctly. You need a small modification to see the last output: add `printf("\n")` after the end of the loop to flush the output that would otherwise stay in the buffer.

Comment: Write to `stderr` and see if the same happens. If it works there, you have a caching problem.

Comment: Why did you put the newline at the start of the print string instead of the end?  Is there some site that recommends it, for some reason?  Every time, it causes problems:(